# Is $f(\sqrt{x}) = \sqrt{f(x)}$ true, where $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all positives $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functions, logarithms, functional-equations

Is $f(\sqrt{x}) = \sqrt{f(x)}$ true, where $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all positives $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$?

It's obviously false. But the point is that "can it be proved without using the fact that the function satisfies $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$ is logarithms?"

Comment: It suffice to find a counter example.

Comment: $f(x)=f(\sqrt x * \sqrt x)=2f(\sqrt x)\;\Rightarrow\;f(\sqrt x)=\frac 12\,f(x)$

Answer (score 4):

All you need to know is that a logarithm is **one** of the functions that satisfies this equation.  In particular, take $f(x) = \log_{10}(x)$ (any choice of logarithm works here).  We know that $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$, which was the desired property.

*However*, we note that
$$
f(\sqrt{10}) =  \frac 12 \neq \sqrt{f(10)} = 1
$$
So, this $f$ is a *counterexample* to your claim.

---

**Note:** if there were no $f$ satisfying the equality except for $f(x) = 0$, then the claim would be true.  So, we *need* to have some kind of example function.  If logarithms are the only example functions available, then we need to use a logarithm.